# Laravel Blade access object property using variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

In a blade template y controller passes a object which has few values in properties as bellow

```
value_L1 = "Hello"
value_L2 = "Stack"
value_L3 = "OverFlow"
```

I want to use a for loop to display these values but the statement in loop returns null, how can I do such a thing in blade?

```
@for ($count = 1; $count < 3; $count++)
    {{ $object->{'value_L.$count'} }}
@endfor
```

I am able to access these properties as following

```
{{ $object->value_L1 }}
{{ $object->value_L2 }}
```

Thanks,

K

Comment: Single quotes will treat strings as literals, meaning your `$count` will be treated as a string `$count` not as the variable `$count`. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

Comment: Plus he has a dot between the `L` and the `$count`

Comment: I saw this to access a property using a variable `$object->{'$var'}` where `$var="value_L1"` that worked.

Comment: Doesn't ``$object->{'value_L'.$count}`` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
@for ($count = 1; $count < 3; $count++)
    {{ object_get($object, "value_L{$count}" ) }}
@endfor
```

Comment: Excellent! Can you please mark it as correct answer?

Comment: Yes I will, I am testing his edit, and also when i try `@if (isset(object_get($object, "value_L{$count}" )))` it gives syntax error

Comment: do you have `@endif`?

Comment: When I search on object_get I see no info on php.net or laravel documentation. Does it return false or null if property it is trying to access isn't available?

Comment: Yes I have `@endif`, in fact I have a `@else` followed by `@endif`

Comment: It is a laravel function, similar to `array_get()`, and also there is a third function called `data_get()` that works for both arrays and objects. You can take a look at it here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-array-get

Comment: and yes it will return false if you try to access a property that is not available.

Comment: Right, I checked it returns null if property doesn't exist so now I can use it in if without isset. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92540/discussion-between-karmendra-and-glad-to-help).